# Setup Django-SHOP on Divio

Tags: django, divio, django-shop

Tell me, is it possible to install django-shop on Divio servers?
How can I do that?

I can’t imagine how this can be done, because the structure of files in divio is different from the structure of ordinary django projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special at all about the structure of Django projects (or any other projects) in Divio applications.

If using the default Aldryn Django project type, then it starts with a particular project layout, but you are free to use this or not. Projects run in Docker and at the Python/Django level can be configured as you please.

See [How to install Python dependencies in a project](https://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/install-python-dependencies/), and [additional information on managing settings with Aldryn Django](https://docs.divio.com/en/latest/reference/configuration-settings-file/).

Comment: Is it possible to install django-shop using bash? I don’t yet understand how django-shop is installed using the instructions you sent me. Divio is too unusual for me. And therefore it is very interesting